# Magit Tramp not showing diff window

Tags: magit, tramp, diff

When using magit on a local file, I stage my changes and
I then press `c` and `c` again to commit. I **get a new window showing the diff and a window for the commit message**. I write my commit message press `C-c C-c` and the diff and commit window close.

However when using magit on a remote file using tramp, if I stage a change then press `c and c` again to commit, I only get a new window for the commit message **not the diff window**. I can write the commit message as normal,  but not being able to see the diff at this point is annoying.

One thing I noticed is that if I do not stage my changes when using magit on tramp and I go to commit, I **DO** get a diff window, with the message in the message buffer "Nothing staged. Stage and commit all unstaged changes?(Y or n)" I can then then type Y to make the commit. But this way is only allowing me to see a diff for all changes to be placed in one commit, rather than the bits I want to stage for a commit.

How can I get magit to open the diff window when the commit message window is opened on a remote file using tramp?

Comment: If you hit `C-c C-d` (`magit-diff-while-committing`) in the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffer, does it bring up the diff?

Comment: That does show the diff - thanks for that :) But it would still be good for that to come up automatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly show the diff using <kbd>C-d C-d</kbd> in the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffer.

Normally the diff is automatically shown by `magit-commit-diff`, which is a member of `server-switch-hook`. That hook isn't run when committing over Tramp because in that case we cannot use the `emacsclient` to connect to the server (`server.el`) running inside Emacs. Instead an alternative implementation is used, which communicates on standard output/input. That doesn't call that hook.

Comment: for me it is C-c C-d and 'magit-diff-while-committing'